# How to change jquery UI vertical tabs to float right and direction rtl

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Here what i have currently:

[image]

I want to make it direction rtl , all the ul to the right, the same as now just for direction rtl sites, can't find in google or here , how to make it ?

Thanks in advance.

***Code***

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
$( "#tabs li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );

});


 $(function() {
    //  jQueryUI 1.10 and HTML5 ready
    //      http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#removed-cookie-option 
    //  Documentation
    //      http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active
    //      http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate
    //      http://balaarjunan.wordpress.com/2010/11/10/html5-session-storage-key-things-to-consider/
    //
    //  Define friendly index name
    var index = 'key';
    //  Define friendly data store name
    var dataStore = window.sessionStorage;
    //  Start magic!
    try {
        // getter: Fetch previous value
        var oldIndex = dataStore.getItem(index);
    } catch(e) {
        // getter: Always default to first tab in error state
        var oldIndex = 0;
    }
    $('#tabs').tabs({
        // The zero-based index of the panel that is active (open)
        active : oldIndex,
        // Triggered after a tab has been activated
        activate : function( event, ui ){
            //  Get future value
            var newIndex = ui.newTab.parent().children().index(ui.newTab);
            //  Set future value
            dataStore.setItem( index, newIndex ) 
        }
    }); 
    }); 

</script>
```

**html:**

```
<div id="tabs" style="margin-right:22px;width:95%;">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1" >ראשי</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2" >הגדרות חשבון</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3" >חשבוניות</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-4" >עזרה</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="tabs-1">
      <h2>ראשי</h2>
      <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-2">
      <h2>Content heading 2</h2>
      <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-3">
      <h2>Content heading 3</h2>
      <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
      <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-4">
      <h2>Content heading 3</h2>
      <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT(Kheema):**

[image]

**Latest EDIT(for Irvin):**

[image]

This my latest solution (almost perfect) for my needs.

Comment: you should provide some raw code to get better answers. And if you don't provide any code moderators can flag your question.

Comment: you can give `float:right` to `<ul>` then to change `direction` use `direction:rtl`

so it would be like this <ul style="float:right; direction:rtl;">

Comment: @Era is totally right, you should give some information value, otherwise no one can give you the accurate answer. Please be patient and cooperate with us.

Comment: Kheema,i already tryed it but look what happens,i will edit my code with picture .also i tryed to play with the LI,but it wont take effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the code you added I can provide you only this solution : [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n4UGV/1/)

And you need to modify your css like this:

```
.ui-tabs-vertical { width: 55em; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav { padding: .2em .2em .2em 0em; float: right; width: 12em; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li { clear: left; width: 100%; border-bottom-width: 1px !important; border-right-width: 0 !important; margin: 0 -1px .2em 0; direction:rtl;}
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a { display:block; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active { padding-bottom: 0; padding-right: .1em; border-right-width: 1px; border-left-width: 1px; }
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel { padding: 1em;margin-right:13em; direction:rtl;}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a { float:none;}
```

Comment: Thanks, i did it too,but its not the same as the orignal..look my last edit,the last pic i added,is the same as ur solution

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your css as following:

```
.tabs-right .ui-tabs-nav { 
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0.25em; 
    top: 0.25em; 
    bottom: 0.25em; 
    width: 10em; 
    padding: 0.2em 0.2em 0.2em 0em; 
} 
.tabs-right .ui-tabs-nav li { 
    width: 100%; 
    border-left: none; 
    border-bottom-width: 1px !important; 
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px; 
    border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
} 
.tabs-right .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected, 
.tabs-right .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-active { 
    left: -1px; 
    border-left: 1px solid transparent; 
} 
.tabs-right .ui-tabs-nav li a { 
    width: 100%; 
} 

.tabs-right .ui-tabs-panel {
     padding: 1em;
     margin-right:11em;
     direction:rtl;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/H48RU/

Comment: WOW,nice almost perfect just need few changes,look my latest pic any suggest?

Answer (score 0):

it's very easy. create another ****css file**** and import this code

```
.ui-tabs { direction: rtl; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-selected,
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-default {float: right; }
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a { float: right; }




Now your Tab right to left
```